# sql query group by a particular results as a combination value of two field values

Tags: mysql, sql

My message table contains two fields, `senderid` and `recipientid`. I need to list all messages but the combination of values in `senderid` and `recipientid` don't need to repeat.

For example if `senderid = 4` and `recipientid = 2`, I need only one combination value of this; either it is 4,2 or its is 2,4.

Can any one help me in doing this?

Thanks in advance ;)

Comment: can you add schema and sample records?

Comment: hi John Woo This is as my Message table look like

Comment: id | courseid | senderid | recipientid | message              createdOn           | read

Answer (score 0):

```
select
    message,
    case when senderid < recipientid then recipientid else senderid end,
    case when senderid < recipientid then senderid else recipientid end
from m
group by
    message,
    case when senderid < recipientid then recipientid else senderid end,
    case when senderid < recipientid then senderid else recipientid end
```

Answer (score 0):

```
select *
from myTable a
where not exists
(
    select top 1 1 
    from myTable b
    where a.senderId = b.receiverId
    and a.receiverId = b.senderId
    and a.senderId < b.senderId
)
```

Comment: I prefer @Roman's answer to my own - since he's gone with the group by specified in the question whilst I assumed you just wanted to remove duplicate entries. Leaving my entry here as an alternative should it be of use to anyone else.

Answer (score 0):

Idea is simple, just make sure the sender/recipient IDs are concatenated in the way such that the smaller IDs is in front of the larger IDs.

```
select
  pair, count(*) 
from 
  (select if(senderid<recipientid, concat(senderid, ',', recipientid), concat(recipientid,',',senderid)) as pair from messages) pairs
group by pair;
```

Mind the performance of such selection. Maybe you would like to create an additional column to store the pair value when inserting the record, and have the column indexed.